# visual studo item template with wizard and T4

Tags: c#, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2012, t4

I am looking for a sample on how to create an item template with Wizard in Visual Studio 2012.

I need a wizard like MVC Controller.

When the user selects Add Item, I want to show a dialog where the user enters some input parameters, including a class in the solution.

Then on pressing OK we generate a Form (including designer and resx) which we want to add to the project.

Currently I have the T4 files and a program that already does this, but using external tools (TextTransform.exe), copying the files in the folder of the solution and manipulating the csproj file manually.

```
// Set text transform program (this could change according to the Windows version)    
p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\microsoft shared\\TextTemplating\\11.0\\TextTransform.exe";

// Specify T4 template file    
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-out " + "\"" + output + "\"" + " \"" + template + "\"";

//manipulating the csproj    
var formNode = new XElement(@"{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}Compile", new XAttribute("Include", fromPath));
                formNode.Add(new XElement(@"{http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003}SubType", "Form"));
    programNode.AddBeforeSelf(formNode);
```

Comment: I cant discern a question in all this.  You have a T4 template that generates the code, but you have to copy it manually?  And you want to automate that?

Comment: I have a program (winForms), this generate the files (form, resx and designer) based on T4, copy output files on the solution folder and add the files to csproj. I need a item template to do the same, like MVC Controller Item template.